# Chrome dev tools's "show more" shows incorrect size

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have a really simple script that creates a large string

```
window.big = '';
for(let c = 0; c < 12000; c++){
    window.big += 'L'
}
```

Things get weird when I try to `console.log` it.

`window.big.length` is 12000, however, when I try to do `console.log(window.big)` in Chrome Dev Tools, it says `Show more (23.4 KB)`, more than double the original size, which was 12000.

`String.length` may be different compared to the byte size of the characters, however, things get interesting when you try to do

```
var blob = new Blob([window.big], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

which showed a size of 12KB

Replicated the issue on Chrome OS, Chrome Version 80.0.3987.162 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image: Picture of chrome dev tools issue]
[image: Picture of downloaded file size]

Comment: Why do you think the amount of letters has any correlation to the "byte size" of the string\?

Comment: because the downloaded blob size is around 12KBs

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. This provides insight into the differences between Blob and javascript string and people who have this kind of question don't expect to know first hand that it is related to the byte size differences of Blob and javascript @wOxxOm

Comment: may you post that as the answer? thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome devtools has always shown the size of the internal string which is stored in UTF-16 encoding per JavaScript specification so each character occupies two bytes. When you create a `Blob` it stores strings as UTF-8 where ASCII characters (such as `L`) occupy only one byte.

It was fixed in Chrome 83 (see [crbug.com/1024721](https://crbug.com/1024721)). Now Chrome counts byte size of a string using UTF-8 encoding as it's prevalent in the web so now devtools shows 12 kB for your test.